# Center icon over img in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a font-awesome icon that stands on top of an `img` tag, the problem is that it's not centered. And it displays in a different position on every breakpoint in Bootstrap.

How can I absolutely center the icon and keep it at the center no matter what size the screen is?

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/halnex/ye3ppgej/2/

HTML

```
<div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
  <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-4x"></i>
    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/250x180" />
    <div class="caption">The Title</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.thumbnail i {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the `img` and `i` in an element together, set `position: relative` on the common parent, then use a combination of `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` to absolutely center the icon

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
}

.img i {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
      <div class="img">
        <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-4x"></i>
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="caption">The Title</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
      <div class="img">
        <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-4x"></i>
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="caption">The Title</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
      <div class="img">
        <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-4x"></i>
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="caption">The Title</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
      <div class="img">
        <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-4x"></i>
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="caption">The Title</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
      <div class="img">
        <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-4x"></i>
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="caption">The Title</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
transform: translate(0%,-50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(0%,-50%);
-moz-transform: translate(0%,-50%);
-o-transform: translate(0%,-50%);
```

Snippet below

[fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/opxjoqrj/)

Comment: That still requires setting a fixed margin based on the amount of text in the caption. If you add more text to the caption, the icon isn't centered. https://jsfiddle.net/opxjoqrj/1/

Comment: got me there buddy

Comment: Saw you change your pic..puppet? hee hee

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `flex` layout for centering:

You would have to adjust your html / css a little bit:

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <div class="icon-wrap">
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-4x"></i>
    </div>
    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/250x180" />
    <div class="caption">The Title</div>
</a>

.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
}

.icon-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

You could add `margin-bottom` to the `.icon-wrap i` if you need to adjust for the title.

You could also set the `height` to `180px` if its always going to contain that size image